# Why Can't I Get The Data I Want From This Enum?

Tags: java, for-loop, enums, equals

I need to know:
Why can't I pass maxSpeed to method as an int rather than Integer?

Why does it work using "getMaxSpeed.equals(speed)" method but can't compare less than/greater than? (I think because of maxSpeed being Integer rather than int, right?). The code doesn't compile with compareTo.

I need to get a list of all cars with maxSpeed greater than 'speed', how do I do this?

How can I return not only the name(BMW, Mercedes) but also the engineCc?

Tried using both normal operators for primitives and methods for objects.

```java
enum CarData {

    BMW (230, 3000),
    Mercedes (220, 2500);

        private int maxSpeed;       
        private int engineCc;

        CarData (int maxSpeed, int engineCc) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.engineCc = engineCc;
        }

        Integer getMaxSpeed(){
        return maxSpeed;
        }

        int getEngineCc() {
        return engineCc;
        }

    public static CarData getByMaxSpeed (int speed) {
    for (CarData carData : CarData.values()){
    if (carData.getMaxSpeed() => speed) 
        return carData;
        }
    return null;
    }
}

public class VehicleInfo {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        System.out.println (CarData.getByMaxSpeed(200));

    }
}
```

Expected result is "BMW, Mercedes" or "3000, 2500", whichever one I need.

Comment: "*`if (carData.getMaxSpeed() => speed) `*" - this should not compile. Swap `=>` around to `>=`.

Comment: "Whichever one I need"? No, the computer will not find out what you need. You need to tell him. In your case, it will return the enum as defined by the return value.

Comment: Yeah I know I have to tell it what to do, it isn't going to do it for me, I'd just like to know what the code is in both cases

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive data type in Java.
Integer is a wrapper class. You can't compare instances of a wrapper class (like Integer) in the same way you do with primitives, with Integer you have to use methods, with primitives it is simpler. 
For the output try overriding the toString method in your enum, this toString method is inherited from the Object class. 
The complete class would be

```
enum CarData {

BMW(230, 3000),
Mercedes(220, 2500);

private int maxSpeed;
private int engineCc;

/* This method was added/overwritten */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name() + ", Cc: " + engineCc;
}

CarData(int maxSpeed, int engineCc) {
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.engineCc = engineCc;
}

Integer getMaxSpeed() {
    return maxSpeed;
}

int getEngineCc() {
    return engineCc;
}

public static CarData getByMaxSpeed(int speed) {
    for (CarData carData : CarData.values()) {
       //Here I replaced the => by >=
        if (carData.getMaxSpeed() >= speed) {
            return carData;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

public class VehicleInfo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(CarData.getByMaxSpeed(200));

}
```

}
}

And the output:

BMW, Cc: 3000

If you want a different string just customize the return in the toString method, also you have to replace the => by >= to make the comparison.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so changing the operator to >= worked, the only problem is I want to show all with a top speed greater than 200, i.e. BMW and Mercedes not just BMW